# addEventListener doesn't work well with window.onload?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I was trying to run the code below but addEventListner wasn't working, then I figured out that it's not working with window.onload so I commented it out
But I don't know why? or if I made a mistake?

```
// window.onload = () => {
//     if (sessionStorage["firstCountry"] != "")
//         document.querySelector(
//             "body"
//         ).innerHTML += `<div> First country is: ${sessionStorage["firstCountry"]}`;
// };
document.querySelector("#check").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using DOMContentLoaded to replace window.onload

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    console.log("DOMContentLoaded");
    ...
});
```